# Calling a local function from a dot sourced file

Tags: powershell

I have a main script that I am running.  What it does is read through a directory filled with other powershell scripts, dot includes them all and runs a predefined method in each made up of the first portion of the dot delimited file name.  Example:

1. Run master.ps1
2. Master.ps1 dot sources .\resource\sub.ps1
3. Sub.ps1 has defined a function called 'dosub'
4. Master.ps1 runs 'dosub' using Invoke-Expression

Also defined in sub.ps1 is the function 'saysomething'.  Implemented in'dosub' is a call to 'saysomething'.

My problem is I keep getting the error:

> The term 'saysomething' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Why can't the method 'dosub' find the method 'saysomething' which is defined in the same file?

master.ps1:

```
$handlersDir = "handlers"

$handlers = @(Get-ChildItem $handlersDir)

foreach ( $handler in $handlers ) {

    . .\$handlersDir\$handler

    $fnParts = $handler.Name.split(".")

    $exp = "do" + $fnParts[0]
    Invoke-Expression $exp
}
```

sub.ps1:

```
function saysomething() {
    Write-Host "I'm here to say something!"
}


function dosub() {
    saysomething
    Write-Host "In dosub!"
}
```

Comment: Your example works for me. Is what you posted exactly what you are running are your system?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my system. However you can simplify it a bit:

```
$handlersDir = "handlers"

$handlers = @(Get-ChildItem $handlersDir)
foreach ( $handler in $handlers ) 
{
    . .\$handlersDir\$handler

    $exp = "do" + $handler.BaseName
    Write-Host "Calling $exp"
    & $exp
}
```

Note the availability of the `BaseName` property.  You also don't need to use `Invoke-Expression`.  You can just call the named command ysing the call (`&`) operator.

Comment: Well, the strange part here to me is that I'm seeing the Write-Host output of "In dosub!" as well as the 'The term 'saysomething' is not recognized...' error.  This means my master script is seeing, sourcing and running code in the 'sub' files.  That rules out "normal" environment misconfigurations and leaves only the more mysterious possibilities.  I'll try it on a different machine and see if I have any better luck.

Comment: I did my test on PowerShell v2.  Are you on v1?

Answer (score 0):

What you have given works as needed. You probably don't have the directories etc proper on your machine. Or you are running something else and posting a different ( working!) code here.

You can also make following corrections:

```
. .\$handlersDir\$handler
```

instead of above you can do:

```
. $handler.fullname
```

Instead the splitting of the filename you can do:

```
$exp = "do" + $handler.basename
```

Comment: Thanks for the basename pointer, I'll switch that out right now. As for the code, I'm pasting it straight out of the file no changes nada!

Comment: @QuinnPeters - It works for me. Make sure you have the handlers directory and the files within it. Something might be wrong in your "environment".